# How to solve Nonlinear least squares problem?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, optimization

[image]

Initial idea is to use euclidean distances. But I do not understand how should I solve this task.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know the solution but I will try like below

- Two stations are enough to know position . Since  station has error , we need more measurements
- we draw 4 circles. 2 circles from each station. One circle with radius distance - error and other with radius distance plus error
- By solving four circle equation , we will get a patch where mobile lies
- a new station will benefit if it’s error is less than the error of any of two stations.